# How do I detect a custom plugin in Firefox/IE/Chrome?

Tags: c#, javascript, c++, browser, plugins

My team wants to build a "plugin" for firefox/chrome/IE.
How do I use javascript to detect if this plugin (not extension) is installed?

I would like to have a piece of **javascript** that can detect if a certain plugin is installed.  Returns true if installed, returns false otherwise.

For example...how do I get a list of plugins, and then loop through to see if one of them match my plugin name? If match, return 1.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
solved:

document.writeln("<TABLE BORDER=1><TR VALIGN=TOP>",
   "<TH ALIGN=left>i",
   "<TH ALIGN=left>name",
   "<TH ALIGN=left>filename",
   "<TH ALIGN=left>description",
   "<TH ALIGN=left># of types</TR>")
for (i=0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) {
   document.writeln("<TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>",i,
      "<TD>",navigator.plugins[i].name,
      "<TD>",navigator.plugins[i].filename,
      "<TD>",navigator.plugins[i].description,
      "<TD>",navigator.plugins[i].length,
      "</TR>")
}
document.writeln("</TABLE>")
```

Comment: Maybe you could accept the answer of @Matt, who pointed out the `navigator.plugins` ability?

Comment: I tried, but it won't let me.  For some reason the check is locked

Answer (score 13):

`navigator.plugins` will have an array of plugins that you can check.

This exists for Firefox, Chrome, and IE (at least version 8, I don't have a lower version to test)

Here's what the array looks like in webkit:

[image: Plugins Array in Webkit]

Comment: Browser DOM capabilities have really evolved so much. Nice.

Comment: hello Matt,
i tried to use navigator.plugins to detect plugins installed on client machine. but it doesn't work with IE. can you guide me in that please?

Answer (score 4):

You can get browser plugins by this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=navigator.plugins.length; // store the total no of plugin stored 
var txt="Total plugin installed: "+x+"<br/>";
txt+="Available plugins are->"+"<br/>";
for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
{
  txt+=navigator.plugins[i].name + "<br/>"; 
}
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;
</script>
<br/>
<script>
```