# how to detect if the rss plugin is already installed on chrome?

Tags: php

how to detect if the rss extension is already installed in Chrome using php/javascript?

Please help me..

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

navigator.plugins and javascript is probably what you need, check this answer:
[How do I detect a custom plugin in Firefox/IE/Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892064/how-do-i-detect-a-custom-plugin-in-firefox-ie-chrome)

Comment: Hi Ajweb, I tried it but it doesn't detect the chrome rss extension. I already installed the rss extension but I dont know why it doesnt detect.