# Check if PDF viewer plugin is installed in IE/Chrome/FireFox/Safari

Tags: c#

I am trying to create function that will essentially check if there is any PDF Viewer [Adobe or any other] is installed as Plugin for browser.

For example: 
I someone click on link in webpage it will open up the PDF file instead of showing option to download, this means a PDF viewer plugin is present in browser.

**I have my help on internet for this but none of them is with C# code.**

- Most of them is either JavaScript to check the plugins
- others are there to check if Adobe PDF viewer is installed on the machine.

Comment: Use the second approach and rewrite it in C#?

Comment: It is going to be a lot of work if you want to support every browser and every such plugin.

Comment: I have to check for 4 browser that is mentioned in the question.

Comment: I know that Chrome has built in, so just want to check from my C# code to see if it present. Likewise for other browser.

Comment: Isn't normal behaviour that the browser will show the PDF if it has a plugin, rather than downloading it? Are you doing this from a web application?

Comment: From *where* do you want to check this? Server-side C# code cannot access the client-side browser. Or do you have a desktop application that should check the locally installed browser?

Comment: Consider I am running a console app on any system which has IE/Chrome/FF browser installed. This will only check if the PDF viewer plugin installed or not. Simply by checking a registry/file etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a pure C# solution, I am not sure where you would want to run it, how would you go about using C# on a browser unless you are working server side? you can try the below as soon as you load your browser page and just save the details to the session variable if asp.net, then you always have a reference to the status of weather the plugin is installed or not.

You cant try a few ways to solve the issue, the first and simplest would be to just create a simple [object tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.pdf">
    <p>Browser does not support PDF</p>
</object>
```

You can render this on a different page and just query if the control comes up or if the **Browser does not support PDF** message is shown,might as well just hide it, render it and then check it.

Or you could use the [NavigatorPlugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/plugins) that you can go through and find if there is anything related to PDF

You can check a reference to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892064/how-do-i-detect-a-custom-plugin-in-firefox-ie-chrome)

Comment: As I said earlier, I just want to use C# to check whether the plugin exist or not. In other word, does it have some information in some file/registry etc.